# Visual Studio shortcut key for edit-and-continue: pause, (compile) and then run again

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-assist, edit-and-continue

Is there a shortcut key for pause and then, run again immediately after compilation?
It will be helpful when debugging while doing edit and continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, just realized there is Apply Code changes: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>